# Scraped data getting printed to csv in a single line

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, web-crawler

Running my crawler I could see that it fetches data as it should but when it comes to print the data to a csv file, it prints that in a single line. I'm very new to work with class in python so there may be numerous mistakes in my code which I have written hypothetically seeing different examples. So, at this point I wish to fix the single line printing and make it go down creating new lines. Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

```
import csv
import requests
from lxml import html

class wiseowl:
    def __init__(self,start_url):
        self.start_url=start_url
        self.storage=[]

    def crawl(self):
        self.get_link(self.start_url)


    def get_link(self,link):
        response=requests.get(link)
        tree=html.fromstring(response.text)
        titles=tree.xpath("//p[@class='woVideoListDefaultSeriesTitle']")
        for title in titles:
            name=title.xpath(".//a/text()")[0]
            urls=title.xpath(".//a/@href")[0]
            Docs=(name,urls)
            self.storage.append(Docs)


    def writing_csv(self):
        with open("Wiseowl.csv","w",newline="") as f:
            writer=csv.writer(f)
            writer.writerow(["Title","Link"])
            writer.writerow(self.storage)


    def __str__(self):  
        return "{}".format(self.storage)


crawler=wiseowl("http://www.wiseowl.co.uk/videos/")
crawler.crawl()
crawler.writing_csv()
for item in crawler.storage:
    print(item)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have  understood you correctly you already have the answer in your code where you print out the `crawler.storage` line by line.

Just change the method `writing_csv` to this:

```
def writing_csv(self):
    with open("Wiseowl.csv","w",newline="") as f:
        writer=csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(["Title","Link"])

        for item in self.storage:
            writer.writerow(item)
```

When you use `writer.writerow(self.storage)` the method `writerow` considers `self.storage` as one line string. This is why it stores it as one line in the file.

Note I run the code using python3.

Comment: Thanks Nurzhan, for such a wonderful solution. It works perfect. Gonna accept your answer in a while. One more thing to know: if i wanted to use "name" and "urls" from get_link method to "dunder str" method instead of using "self.storage", should I have called that using self.name and self.urls?

Comment: @SMth80, If you want to access your variables `name` and `urls` using `self.name` and `self.urls` in the `__str__` method, then you need to declare them as instance variables in the constructor method `__init__` of your `wiseowl class`. For instance, `self.name = ""` and `self.urls = ""`. But since you deal with a collection of name and url pairs then your current solution is fine. You put your pairs of names and urls (which are tuples) into the `storage` list and then access them from there. Hope I answered your question.

Comment: Thanks a trillion. Your answer with couple of lines saved my years effort.